# SQL Server, ordering with variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I understand that I have to use cases to be able to use variables, but how can I make one that includes direction as well (`asc`, `desc`) preferably with if/else or something similar.

I have a variable called `@orderDirection` for this purpose. Which can have either `asc` or `desc` as the value.

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @order = 1 THEN [date_time] END,
    CASE WHEN @order = 2 THEN [company] END,
    CASE WHEN @order = 3 THEN [country_1] END,
    CASE WHEN @order = 4 THEN [country_2] END,
    [date_time]
```

I would like to have else included in this, so if it isn't `desc` then it should always be ascending order, even if this value is something else entirely.

Something like this:

```
IF @orderDirection = 'desc' THEN
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @order = 1 THEN [date_time] END desc,
        CASE WHEN @order = 2 THEN [company] END desc,
        CASE WHEN @order = 3 THEN [country_1] END desc,
        CASE WHEN @order = 4 THEN [country_2] END desc,
        [date_time]
ELSE
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @order = 1 THEN [date_time] END asc,
        CASE WHEN @order = 2 THEN [company] END asc,
        CASE WHEN @order = 3 THEN [country_1] END asc,
        CASE WHEN @order = 4 THEN [country_2] END asc,
        [date_time]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with dynamic SQL.  But with regular SQL, list out each option:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @order = 1 AND @orderDirection = 'desc' THEN [date_time] END ) desc,
         (CASE WHEN @order = 2 AND @orderDirection = 'desc' THEN [company] END) desc,
         (CASE WHEN @order = 3 AND @orderDirection = 'desc' THEN [country_1] END) desc,
         (CASE WHEN @order = 4 AND @orderDirection = 'desc' THEN [country_2] END) desc,
         (CASE WHEN @order = 1 AND @orderDirection = 'asc' THEN [date_time] END ),
         (CASE WHEN @order = 2 AND @orderDirection = 'asc' THEN [company] END),
         (CASE WHEN @order = 3 AND @orderDirection = 'asc' THEN [country_1] END),
         (CASE WHEN @order = 4 AND @orderDirection = 'asc' THEN [country_2] END),
         [date_time]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your query in a CTE and create an integer ID field, then order by that field either positively or negatively:

```
declare @orderDirection varchar(4) = 'asc'
,@order int = 1

;with a as(
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
                         CASE WHEN @order = 1 THEN [date_time] END,
                         CASE WHEN @order = 2 THEN [company] END,
                         CASE WHEN @order = 3 THEN [country_1] END,
                         CASE WHEN @order = 4 THEN [country_2] END,
                         [date_time]
                         ) AS ID
...    --other fields
FROM [table]
)

SELECT
*
FROM a
ORDER BY (ID * case when @orderDirection = 'asc' then 1 else -1 end)
```

Comment: this is a flexible way of doing this.  But I would recommend expanding your answer and showing how the OP would use the case expression in the ORDER BY of the ROW_NUMBER() windowed function so that it is a bit more complete